# show next and previous button in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an array of a video object and used `AVQueuePlayer` for playing videos in the queue (one after another). Now when the user plays the video, instead of the forward and backward button I want to display the next and previous button so the user can go to the next or previous video but I don't know how to show that button any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
let item1 = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!)
        let item2 = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")!)
        let item3 = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!)

        let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [item1, item2, item3])
        queuePlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .advance

        let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
        vc.showsPlaybackControls = true
        vc.player = queuePlayer
```

Comment: Could you post your code? I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Frankenstein code added